# How can I prevent infinite recursion when declaring two object each containing the other?

Tags: java, oop

its my first question and I am already nervous. I may start with "Its for my homework" and it is but i try to get to the problem:
I have to realise a simple ticket selling program, that contains two classes:
a class ticket which contains the following fields:

```
public class Ticket
{
    //Fields
    private int ticketID;
    private boolean sold;
    private Category category;

    //Constructor
    public Ticket(int ticketID, Category category)
    {
        this.ticketID = ticketID;
        this.category = category;
        this.sold = false;
    }
}
```

and a class named Category which should look like this:

```
public class Category
{
    char category;
    double sellPrice;
    Ticket[] tickets;

    private Random rnd;

    public Category(char category, double sellPrice, int amount)
    {
        this.category = category;
        this.sellPrice = sellPrice;

        //from here on my difficulties start!
        rnd = new Random(System.nanoTime());

        tickets = new Ticket[amount];
        for(int i = 0; i < tickets.length; i++)
        {
            tickets[i] = new Ticket(generateRandom(100000, 1000000), this); 
            //especially this line worries me!
        }
    }
```

For simplicity I stripped the code down to bare mimimum. Now my problem is that I should create an array of Category which will contain the arrays of Tickets, but when I do that I create an infinite loop by referencing each ticket to the Category object by passing it the "this" for the category parameter of its constructor. Whel debugging my project I really create an "infinite" loop because I can always go deeper into the combination of Category->tickets[]->category->tickets[]->... and so on. The Assignment says I have to use the Category class in Ticket but is there another way to create a system without these "loops"?

Comment: What is the problem having this "infinite loop"?

Comment: I do not see a problem here

Comment: Won't it just reference itself forever?

Comment: Unless you write some code that follows those references forever, no it won't.

Comment: The beauty of references is they can be cyclical - `a` can reference `b` and `b` can reference `a`. You *do* need to be careful how these are used, however. For example if both object's `equals()` reference these cyclical fields the `equals()` method cannot terminate. As long as you take care to avoid infinite recursion in each class' methods there's no issue with cyclic references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I prevent infinite recursion when declaring two object each containing the other?

In your given example, there won't be any problems of so called infinite recursion. That will only happen if you have something like this:

```
class Ticket{
    public Ticket(){
        new Category();
    }
}

class Category{
    public Category(){
        new Ticket();
    }
}
```

> Won't it just reference itself forever?

If you are merely creating a variable, for example:

```
Ticket ticket;
```

The constructor will not be invoked. The constructor will only be invoked when you instantiate the object, i.e.: `new Ticket();`

Answer (score 0):

You are right in that you can always go deeper into the combination of `Category->tickets[]->category->tickets[]->`, etc., and if you do, it's indeed a problem, but you have not shown us any code where you are actually doing it.

References are not instantiations. So in our example, `Category` instantiates a bunch of `Ticket`s, which does take a lot of space; but `Ticket` does not instantiate a `Category` and instead merely refers to it. Which is typically just 64 extra bits per Ticket.

Think about it this way. Instantiations (by calling `new`) is like giving birth. References is like pointing at someone. Two people can point at each other, or many can point at you, and it won't cost much.

It's when you visit person A who points at person B, and then decide to visit A again, then B again, etc., you may get into an infinite loop. The fact they are pointing at each other does not cause any such problem.